# How to print the value of an array instead of the key?

Tags: forms

I have the code below in a form builder for Drupal 7:

```
$form['color'] = array(
  '#type' => 'select',
  '#required' => TRUE,
  '#title' => t('Color:'),
  '#options' => array(
    0 => t('Blue'),
    1 => t('Yellow'),
  )
);
```

I need to print the selected value in hook_mail but I only get the key when I write:

```
function color_mail($key, &$message, $params) {
  global $user;
  $message['subject'] = 'Selected color is: ' . $params['color']
}
```

While what would make sense here would be to print the value, not the key. I tried `$params['color']['#options'];` too but it didn't work.

Any tip on how to make this work? I'm sure it's something simple I don't yet know about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The form submission process will only actually keep hold of the array key (which is the value for the select element), so it won't be available to you in `$params`.

The usual method to handle this sort of thing is to provide a function to return the options:

```
function MYMODULE_colour_options() {
  return array(
    0 => t('Blue'),
    1 => t('Yellow'),
  );
}
```

Then in your form function you would use:

```
$form['color'] = array(
  '#type' => 'select',
  '#required' => TRUE,
  '#title' => t('Color:'),
  '#options' => MYMODULE_colour_options()
);
```

And in the message hook:

```
$colour_options = MYMODULE_colour_options();

$colour_string = 'Unknown';
if (isset($colour_options[$params['color']])) {
  $colour_string = $colour_options[$params['color']];
}

$message['subject'] = 'Selected color is: ' . $colour_string;
```